# Ground Penetrating Radar (GPR) to ESRI raster format

Tags: software-recommendations, esri-grid-format

Can anyone recommend a software package (preferably free) to convert ground penetrating radar data (in .dzt format) into an Esri raster format?

I have come across ZondST2D, but as far as I can tell it will not do the conversion.

Comment: try this site: http://www.geophysical.com/softwareutilities.htm

Comment: I did see this and noticed the ASCII converter on there, but as far as I can tell the .txt file that it converts the .dzt file to isn't recognised as a usable format in ArcMap.

Comment: is it a point cloud? sort of like LIDAR maybe.

Comment: Similar to LIDAR as the data is in a grid format.

Comment: I'm guessing you have vertical tomographic profiles, which from a map perspective would be lines. What are you expecting to process / see?

Comment: Thats a good question, but I guess I'll figure that out once I get the data into Arc - Will perhaps use the grid for viewing in a 3D space via ArcScene and will most likely interpolate between the profiles to produce some horizontal slices.

Comment: As far as I know, ArcGIS doesn't have any native geophysical tools with this capability. Esri rasters are flat on maps, and not vertical.

Comment: Flat in ArcMap absolutely, but a 3D enabled raster will extend into the Z axis which is viewable in ArcScene.

Answer (score 1):

The [free Windows software by Larry Conyers (Denver University)](http://www.gpr-archaeology.com/software/) will convert DZT to a variety of formats including images and surfer grid (raster)

It's based on DOS code from the USGS and hence open source.